# How to bind data depending on if checkbox is checked?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, get

Just getting started on Angular, I'm using checkboxes to determine which parameters get sent during a get request (this is my attempt):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="submit('color[]', 'red')"/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="submit('color[]', 'green')" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="submit('color[]', 'blue')"/>
```

I have a variable `$scope.params` that stores the parameters of my http get request. My submit function is very simple:

```
$scope.submit = function (attribute, value) {
  $scope.params[attribute] = value;
};
```

It simply adds `color[]` to the params object. Unlike radio, checkbox values can be stored as arrays and submitted as such: `api?color[]=red&color[]=green` as my backend is PHP this is the preferred format. However my submit function simply overwrites this every time. I'm not sure how to store multiple params with the same "key".

My other problem is that `ng-click` is not appropriate for this task as it doesn't take in the current state of the checkbox. Notice that my green checkbox is initially loaded as checked. Is there a way to bind this to my `$scope.params` object?

Ideally I want to implement something like:

```
$scope.params = {
  "color[]" = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
};
```

According to Semicolon's answer below, I can use:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="params.colors[]" ng-true-value="'red'"/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="params.colors[]" ng-true-value="'blue'"/>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="params.colors[]" ng-true-value="'green'"/>
```

But naming anything with `"[]"` just breaks the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkboxes, like all input elements, are supported with `ng-model`. This core directive is a cousin of `ng-bind`. It says "the state of this element represents this model". Its behavior is determined by the input type. In the case of a checkbox, the value you are modeling is going to be boolean typically, since a checkbox is fundamentally a "boolean" input (checked/unchecked == true/false).

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="colors.red"/>
```

In the controller function:

```
$scope.colors = {
    red: false,
    green: true,
    blue: false
};
```

Actually you can map checked/unchecked to non-boolean values too, using `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`. You can read more about these and other options for `ng-model` with checkboxes in the Angular docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

The core difference between `ng-bind` and `ng-model` is that the former is unidirectional (just a view) and the latter is bidirectional (the element can be used to change the model).

**A more general answer regarding the premise of MVC in Angular:**

In the example in your question, you were using a jQuery-like solution to try to achieve binding between the view and controller. This is really not ideal. Only bind a function to click events when you are specifically interested in having something take place "on click".

What if a user uses the tab key and the spacebar to check the box? The model would not get updated.

Or let's say you want to change the value in the model somewhere else -- maybe you have a "reset" button that returns them to the original values. The view would not get updated.

If the connection between the view and the model is all through "actions" it is easy for them to be out of sync. You'd have to make sure you handled every possible way the user could interact with the element and each time you change the data programmatically you would need to push the change to the view explicitly. But using `ng-model` and `ng-bind` lets you keep them synced no matter where the model is changed or how the user interacts. Really this is the main point of Angular.

Comment: Yep, I've stopped using `ng-click`. I understand checkboxes are a boolean input but is it possible to add 'red' to the color array (see my latest edit) when ng-true-value and remove it (i.e. no value) when ng-false-value?

Comment: That's a JS question, really, rather than an Angular question. To use brackets in a property name, it must be a string in quotes using bracket notation: `ng-model="params['colors[]']"`

Comment: But note, such naming is a confusing mix of concerns. If your PHP requires such un-javascript-friendly naming conventions, it is better to transform the data when it is actually submitted.

Comment: On further consideration I realize that what you want to do is have an actual array of the values at params.colors (I think?). That's just not how arrays work in JS, there's no such thing as `colors[] = val`, it would be `colors.push(val)` or `colors[0] = val`. You can't exactly do this on the model directly, but you can maintain a link between the colors model as described above and separate `params` model that gets updated according to your needs when they change by using `$scope.$watch`. Or you could address the model values by index, but that would be problematic eg. `[ undefined, 'red' ]`